# Disable work offline in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8

I am using Windows 7, and IE8.
Often, when I have IE8 open, and I resume the computer from sleep, I get the question about working offline - even if at that moment the wireless connection is available.
This is particularly sad, because all browsing is stopped until I dismiss that dialog, that may be hidden below other windows.
This is more frequent if I have GMail open in a tab, but this behavior comes from other sites as well. I suppose, GMail triggers it more often just because of its background updates.

As I am not using offline browsing at all, is it possible to disable the functionality altogether, so that I no longer get the question? A bit like in Firefox, where I simply get the error message with page unavailable.
I have googled a bit, but no luck so far. Even a direct modification of the registry would be fine, for me.

Comment: maybe a good suggestion: avoid using Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 Service Pack 1 contains a fix for this:

[KB982370: You receive a "Work Offline" dialog box in Internet Explorer 8 after the computer resumes from sleep or from hibernation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982370)

> Consider the following scenario:
>   - You use Windows Internet Explorer 8 to browse web pages.
>   - You put the computer to sleep (S3) or into hibernation (S4).
>   - You resume the computer after a while.
>
> In this scenario, you receive a Work Offline dialog box in Internet Explorer 8. However, the computer is connected to the Internet.

Comment: I think you are right, because lately I have not seen that annoying message any longer.

Comment: i decided to troll for some free rep. i read the release notes of SP1, then searched SU for matching problems. Write up an answer, link to the KB article, Bam! :)

Answer (score 1):

> all browsing is stopped until I
>   dismiss that dialog

Use **[ClickOff](http://www.johanneshuebner.com/en/clickoff.shtml)** to 'dismiss that dialog' automatically, It's simple but efficient, this program can kill annoying pop-up messages and windows in a flash.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a workaround, and it is quite interesting.  
However, this is not really the solution - that would be how to disable that request at all.

Comment: wireless network devices and sleep mode has always been dodgy affair and that hasn't much improved with Vista/7. the problem is certainly not with the browser, it's the device configuration. that said, some WLAN adapters are plain cr*p, i hope for you it's not a Ralink adapter :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this fix on a forum, didn't test it.

Look in the registry (START >> RUN >> REGEDIT)

Using regedit, find the folder:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WebCheck

And check that these two *String* keys are set to auto:
"LoadSens"="auto"
"LoadLCE"="auto"
Create them if necessary!

http://www.anetforums.com/posts.aspx?ThreadIndex=4068

Answer (score 0):

Me- Vista with IE 8. I always have a couple of links on my desktop to go to websites other than my homepage so I click one of those, then I receive an IE message that asks me if I want to Connect or Work offline. I click connect.